# Match string with 10 or fewer non-whitespace characters in front of string, ignoring whitespace characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will search for the word `test` and match with the following strings:

```
 test
test
//test
// tests
         // test
  // 1    2 34 test
```

But it would fail against the following:

```
// 1234567890 test
12345678901test
```

So far I have `(?=\S|\s)test([^\n]*)`, which weems to work, aside from the 0-10 non-whitespace characters. [Here's a regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/x4EA4g/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
/^(?=(\s*?\S?){0,10}test).*?test/
```

It uses a positive lookahead to assert the use-case so that the capture doesn't bleed onto other lines.

https://regex101.com/r/x4EA4g/3

Comment: This one looks perfect, thank you! I thought I would have to use lookaheads, but I've barely used them and couldn't work out the secret sauce

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `(?:\s|^)\S{0,10}test`

https://regex101.com/r/M2oLJe/1

Answer (score 0):

The following regex would match strings with 10 or fewer non-whitespace characters in front of `test`, ignoring whitespace characters:

```
(?:^\s*(?:\S\s*){0,10})test.*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/x4EA4g/2